# LSTM model function syntax error on return

Tags: python, function, return

I'm trying to run some lstm models on my local jupyter notebook and this build_model function is not working

```
def build_model(optimizer):
    grid_model = Sequential()
    grid_model.add(LSTM(50,return_sequences=True,input_shape=(30,5)))
    grid_model.add(LSTM(50))
    grid_model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    grid_model.add(Dense(1))
    grid_model.compile(loss = 'mse',optimizer = optimizer)
return grid_modelgrid_model = KerasRegressor(build_fn=build_model,verbose=1,validation_data=(testX,testY))
```

the error message is saying the = sign in the return statement is not working but I don't see why not:

```
return grid_modelgrid_model = KerasRegressor(build_fn=build_model,verbose=1,validation_data=(testX,testY))
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

can someone tell me what's wrong I can't seem to figure out..

Answer (score 0):

do not put '=' on the return line
you can't assigne a variable on the return line